# Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]' when I initialize custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, init

In CustomCell.m I define init method where I want to load cell from the IB:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    return self;
}
```

In the MyTableViewController.m in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath I initialize my custom cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

cell=[[CustomCell alloc]init];
return cell;
```

}

Everything works as I expected but when I did `Product -> Analyse` I get
`Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are overwriting `self` (returned from `super init`) with the object returned from your array. If you want to load a custom cell from a nib, do it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, or create a convenience class method on your custom cell that loads from the nib:

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell = [CustomCell cell];
```

In your cell's implementation:

```
+(CustomCell*)cell
{
    NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];         
    return [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

**EDIT** - changed method name since new* indicates that a retained object will be returned.

Comment: Thanks, But before cell = [CustomCell newCell];
do i need init cell: cell=[[CustomCell alloc]init];

Comment: I did as you explained, and now i got this ! instead of previous one:Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Comment: Oh yes, I've called it newCell which ARC will complain about. I will update the answer, sorry.

Comment: And no, you don't need alloc / init, the cell is brought into memory by loading the nib.

Comment: But if i do the same not for the cell but for custom header, what should i write instead of +(CustomCell*)cell? +(CustomHeader*)view?

Comment: If you like, yes - you'd have to put a similar class method in your header view class.

Answer (score 9):

Keep your init method as below, and do the linking in the Interface Builder

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

And

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I know this method but I prefer to have method init inside the cell.

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing is

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Initialization code.
        //
        UITableViewCell *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SmallCellView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        self.backgroundView = view;
}
    return self;
}
```

then in the main class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SmallCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[SmallCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 }
  return cell;
}
```

For me this is working fine and in `Product -> Analyse` is not giving any warning or error

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, I have fixed it by removing the code that like

```
NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];         
return [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

from the CustomView's definition init Method.

Put these code the at  the place where you create the Custom.